# Are SceneKit eulerAngles Floats or CGFloats?

Tags: swift, scenekit, cgfloat

According to the SceneKit API, euler angles, as a property of SCNNode, are SCNVector3. And SCNVector3 is `{ CGFloat x, y, z: }`. But when I attempt to assign a CGFloat to a eulerAngle property of a node, Xcode claims I'm trying to assign to type 'Float'. Here's a snippet from my `panGesture` handler:

```
    baseNode.eulerAngles.x = newAngleX
```

I can avoid this by casting as Floats but I'm curious, especially since SCNVector3 still seems to accept CGFloats.

Comment: For whatever reason, it is `Float` on iOS and `CGFloat` on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the documentation is wrong. Directly from SceneKit/SceneKitTypes.h:

```
typedef struct SCNVector3 {
    float x, y, z;
} SCNVector3;
```

Which, amongst other things, means they're 32-bit regardless of target, unlike `CGFloat`s. So it's not a mere typedef issue despite the naming similarity — Swift is right to want an explicit cast.